# How can I set or suggest an answer to an unanswered question that is not my own?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encourage users to select ‘Accepted Answer’ for old Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions)

Basically as the title reads. Sometimes I see 'unanswered' questions which do actually have a good answer, only it's not accepted. Is there some way that I can flag an answer as the correct one, even if I didn't ask the question?
I see there is a 'flag' link but the title reads 'flag this post for serious problems', so it would seem like the wrong thing for a correct, but unaccepted answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking about the unanswered tab, applying an upvote to any answer present will [make the questions "answered" for the purpose of the tab](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/).

Acceptance is a whole 'nother matter. It is a decision for the OP to make (exception after offering a bounty and *not* accepting anything in the allotted time an answer *may* be auto accepted). Acceptance mean no more or less than "The OP accepted this answer".

Comment: okay, I get it now. The unanswered tab is really the 'no upvoted answers' tab.

Comment: @aland: bingo.  (btw, which land?)

Answer (score 4):

Some users don't pay attention to their questions to accept answers, and there's no technical solution to fix that.

The only thing you can do as a 3rd party to the question/answer is to upvote what you believe is the correct answer. (Also, you can upvote the question if you feel it's appropriate -- since this shows up in the activity summary, it may draw the asker's attention to the question.)

I think even leaving a comment on the question to get the question-asker to mark an answer as accepted is taking it a step too far. Certainly, flagging is out of the question, and should only be used for instances of misuse/abuse of the system.

Comment: Good answer.  I add only that "accepted" on SO means "accepted by the OP as useful".

Comment: Other forums have a feature like what I suggested here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172843/suggest-post-as-answer-to-a-question
(My post was about suggesting an answer to the OP, not forcing or any of the things the other users mentioned as duplicated)