# How to force the user to mark as solved a solved questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encourage users to select 'Accepted Answer' for old Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions)
>   [Dealing with non-accepting and non-voting users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48269/dealing-with-non-accepting-and-non-voting-users)

While i was surfing on SO i saw many question solved but not mark as solved, what do you think is the right way to force the users who asked a question and got the right answer to mark it as solved ?
There are many ways to do this, but most of them are unfair or can be used by "point's addicted" users.

My idea is, if the user don't visit anymore his question for long time (1 week, 1 month, 1 year) on the SO user panel, near the question have to appear somethink like that: it's your question been answered ? [Yes|No]

If it neither answer to this question for too much time the user have to be marked as leecher.

Comment: could you at least explain why you are -1 me ? thx :)

Comment: Did this feature-request get downvoted or did your actual profile/account get downvoted? There is a difference. And one of those is impossible.

Comment: The site already asks the user "Have you thought about starting a bounty on this question?" or something to that effect

Comment: Well, the feature-request have been downvoted... i can't understand,  it's so bad what I asked  ?
( to be honest I just asked a question and shared my idea )

Comment: @Cesar: People downvote for different reasons on meta than on SO.  A downvote on SO means "this is unclear or not useful,"  while here on meta people just downvote what they don't agree with.  Don't take it personally.  I didn't downvote you, but I also don't feel that people should be forced to accept an answer if, for whatever reason, they don't choose to.  We also don't put negative labels like "leecher" on people for a reason, but prefer instead to focus on the questions and answers.

Comment: @Bill: thanks for the complete answer, I'm still understanding the difference between the 2 network. You answer is clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never force anyone to mark a question solved. If they ask a question and see a right answer and then quit. Then so be it. It's not good but forcing people to do something is not better.

Also, what you might think is the correct answer might not be it for the one who asked the question.

Comment: you read only the title :(

Comment: I don't see what can be added. If it's a leecher, then he will leach and will have a low acceptance % due to that. If it's a hit and run then he will never come back and be able to see some notification.

Comment: this make sense, still new SO philosophy thx.

Comment: and if it is someone with twice their own reputation, had a bounty which was left to expire, while not marking it solved (and no upvotes) - does it mean the answer is incorrect? Does it also mean the person answering has not contributed to SO?