# How does the system guide new users?

Tags: support, comments, new-users, faq-proposed, help

There are several questions here on meta about "How to guide new users" and in particular "How to educate new users about accepting answers" (see [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135493/informing-new-users-of-how-to-accept-answers), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145997/how-should-i-guide-new-users), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145987/how-to-educate-new-users-about-accepting-answers)). A common approach seems to be to comment on the post, pointing to the FAQ or proposing a certain action.

While these [meta-comments are useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146464/191131), they do not directly contribute to the post itself and therefore could also be considered [noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/191131). An alternative to comments is to have the system itself guide new users (see for example [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135509/191131) and [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146422/formalized-reminders-to-guide-new-users-without-comment-noise)).

Before engaging into the comments-vs-system-reminders discussion, we first need to get a canonical answer on this question:

- How does the system **currently** guide (or prod) new users to participate in using the features of the system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### General

- "How it works" section and "Tell me more" button is displayed on the first visit to any Stack Exchange site
- Informed badge for reading the entire about page
- Notifications about new privileges

### Accepting Answers

- Scholar badge for first accepted answer
- +2 reputation for each accepted answers
- *"Don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking its check mark"* note when voting up an answer to your own question ([screen shot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69777/191131))
- *"Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"* note above questions without accepted answer on the questions page in your profile

### Giving Feedback

- Supporter badge for first up vote
- Critic badge for first down vote
- *"Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved"* note when voting down without having commented first
- Commentator badge when posting the 10th comment

### Writing Good Posts

- Editor formatting help is displayed by default
- When asking a question, the system analyzes the question before it is posted, and tries to detect possible issues with the question that would cause it to be closed on the site
- On Stack Overflow only, the Ask Question Wizard guides new users to fill in required parts of their question

### Improving Posts

- Editor badge for first edit
- *"Are you sure you want to answer your question? Comment if you're trying to respond to an answer. Edit your question if you need to add more details."* when trying to answer your own question ([screen shot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237916/191131))
- *"Are you sure you want to add another answer? You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead."* when trying to add an answer to a question you have already answered