# Flag questions as answered

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encourage users to select 'Accepted Answer' for old Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions)

I find it very frustrating that some answers to questions don't get accepted by the question poster, isn't there some way to manually accept answers, probably by moderators or by flagging them?

I do realize that most people don't accept answers because they don't see the concept of SO yet and are new to the whole thing. So they got their answer and never visit the site again until they have the next problem.

Yet, for people that answer questions and the questioner even comments an answer with "thanks, that helped me solve the problem", but STILL don't accept the answer as correct, it's really frustrating.

Is there any way to mark these obvious "not-accepted-but-still-correct" answers as accepted?

I'm not talking utterly unselfish here, because I am now at the point where I just don't bother answering new user's questions, because I know they won't accept the answer anyway, so where's my motivation? Apart from the good will of helping other people, that is...

Comment: This has been beaten to death. No it's not possible. If you're not the OP, the best thing you can do is to upvote the answer you think is the best. And maybe leave a comment to support it to convince others to upvote it as well.

Comment: "I just don't bother answering new user's questions, because I know they won't accept the answer anyway" - wow. Perhaps time for a short break from SO?

Comment: `I find it very frustrating that some answers to questions don't get accepted by the question poster` Why do you care at all? The community will vote the best answer to the top, stop worrying about it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accepting answers is totally voluntary. Same as voting. You can't force someone to do it. And it indicates what answer helped the OP the most. Another person can't decide that for the OP.

Besides new users often accept past answers after realizing how to use the accept mark.

Comment: Yup; I have had answers accepted many, many months later.